# Как правильно изменить реализацию шаблона репозиторий подгружаемого с помощью интерфейсов для инициализации модели?

Tags: laravel, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, laravel-5.7

Доброго времени суток.

Был создан магазин на основе https://github.com/Laracommerce/laracom на ларавел.
В процессе работы было замечено что наряду с подтягиванием реализации под интерфейс вызовом типа:
use App\Shop\Products\Repositories\Interfaces\ProductRepositoryInterface;

связывание которых объявлено в RepositoryServiceProvider (app\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider.php),
используются прямые вызовы типа use App\Shop\Products\Repositories\ProductRepository;
(например здесь app/Shop/Orders/Repositories/OrderRepository.php)

В коде можно найти несколько подобных примеров и чаще всего прямое указание адреса необходимо для вызова конструкции new Repository(ОбъектМодели).

Не нашел однозначного выхода из данной ситуации, прошу совета тех кто сталкивался с примером качественной реализации.

Comment: Сверху в левом углу пишет "Stack overflow на **русском**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, у Вас в коде есть прямые вызовы репозитория, а не через DI, и Вы хотите вызывать его по интерфейсу, а не через new ProductRepository();
Если это так, то вызвать его можно вот так:

```
$productRepository = app(ProductRepositoryInterface, ['modelObject' => $modelObject]);
```

В таком случае будет подключена забинденная реализация интерфейса.

Comment: Благодарю. Вроде того